# django last updated keeps updating when there is no new information

Tags: python, django

I have a `django` model which updates the `last_updated` field even though no information has changed.  (The info comes from a dict via a *scraper*). Sometimes there will be a new product entry, or an update to the entry or often no change. How can I amend so the `last_updated` field is only updated when there is new information for the product (or a new one is created)?

*The model:*

```
class Product(models.Model):
    unique_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)  
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier)
    region = models.ForeignKey(PowerRegion)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Data updated in scraper via:

```
product, created = Product.objects.update_or_create(
    unique_id=product_detail['productId'],
    defaults={
        'name': product_detail['productName'],
        'supplier': supplier,
        'region': region,
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It [looks like](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L469) `update_or_create` calls `Model.save()`. You can easily override the `save()` method of your model to perform some checks, before deciding whether it should be saved (call `super().save()`) or not.

Inside of `save()` you can figure out whether the data has changed. To do so: `self_old = Product.objects.get(pk=self.pk)` and don't forget to catch `Product.MultipleObjectsReturned` and `Product.DoesNotExist`.

Now, to compare `self` with `self_old` you can compare individual fields or use [this snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2281/).

** ***updated*** **

If I think of it now... Just avoid using using `Product.objects.update_or_create`. Here's how you should update the data:

```
defaults = {'name':..., 'supplier':..., ...}
try:
    instance = Product.objects.get(**defaults)
    # if no exception, the product doesn't need to be updated (*1)
except Product.DoesNotExist:
    # the product needs to be created or updated
    try:
        instance = Product.objects.get(pk=product_detail['productId'])
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        # needs to be created
        Product(**defaults).save()
    else:
        # needs to be updated
        instance.update(defaults)
```

Still I know it's more complicated than update_or_create. Tell me if you know the better solution :)

Comment: Thanks, is there not a simpler way, like a combined get_or_create() and update_or_create() method - can't see in the docs a get_or_update_or_create() method?

Comment: Not that I know of. Or... Actually, I will update the answer with the easier solution.

Comment: Thanks. That probably is the simplest approach. I would have thought they would have a single method for this but maybe it's not as standard as I think.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to identify is the fields that are most likely to change when there is a change.
Then do a check to see if product_detail['productId'] exists:
  `Product.objects.get(unique_id=product_detail['productId'])`
if does not exist add a new record to your table.
If it does exist, check if the *fields which are likely to change* have been updated and if not, do nothing else do an update.