# last_updated date and time keeps updating everytime the user logs into the system but doesn't update any of their details in Django

Tags: django, datetime

In my model for user profile, the `profile_last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)` keeps updating every time the relevant profile owner logs in but doesn't update any of their details. Is there a way to fix this? I found this on SO [django last updated keeps updating when there is no new information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367593/django-last-updated-keeps-updating-when-there-is-no-new-information) but it's a bit confusing. Appreciate any help - thanks!

views.py

```
def user_profile_detail_view(request,pk):
try:
    myprofile = get_object_or_404(User, id=pk)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    return redirect('handler404')
```

Comment: What do you want to update?

Comment: I want the date/time to update only when user profile details have been updated by the relevant user. Right now the date/time updates every time the owner logs into the system regardless of them updating any of their profile details

Answer (score 0):

See, the problem with auto_now=True is that the field always gets update whenever the .save() method is called and thus you are seeing an unexpected behaviour.
Instead what you can do is you can remove auto_now or set it to False then always manually update the field using DateTime.

Example:

from datetime import datetime as dt

```
def your_view_function(request):
    #your rest of the function for processing user profile
Models.objects.filter(id=id_of_field_updated).update(profile_last_updated=dt.now())
```

Comment: Thanks @SimbaOG sadly the answer didn't quite work for me but I did do some more research into it with your answer in the back of my mind. I ended up overriding the profile save method in the model and added this line of code to it: ' self.profile_last_updated = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.UTC) ' - cheers!